# $f,g \in L^3$ to prove $|f|=g$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$f,g \in L^3$ to prove $|f|=g$ a.e.

Given $\|f\|_3 = \|g\|_3 = \int_X f^2g = 1$

If anyone could provide any hint, it would be really helpful

Comment: There's a lot already wrong here, for one thing until you know $g \geq 0$ you don't know that $\int g^3 = \| g \|_3^3$ so your main step doesn't even work. Instead of going this way, notice that you can frame everything in the givens in terms of $h:=f^2$: you know $\|h \|_{3/2}=1$ and $\int h g = 1$. Now notice that $3/2$ is the Holder conjugate of $3$...

Comment: By the way, although it's good to pick tags that match up, it's also generally good to pick tags that are broad enough that a decent number of people follow them. lebesgue-integral and lebesgue-measure are not very popular tags.

Comment: You start is wrong. It should be: $$\|g-|f|\|_3^3= \int_X \left|g(x)-|f(x)|\right|^3$$

Comment: @Ian. Thank you for your hint. I am assuming I now have to apply holders inequality, but to what, if you could give another hint, please.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your hint. I am assuming I now have to apply holders inequality, but to what, if you could give another hint, please.

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron It should really be immediate when you apply Holder to $h$ and $g$...